# Adding nested if else statements inside div

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I have a problem, how to specify which picture should be added when value changes from certain point. I know i have done wrong coding but its because i don't know how to do it.

```
<img if({{h}} > 10): src="img/Weather_icon/11.png" style="width:90px;height:90px;" else if({{h}}>20):src="img/Weather_icon/11.png"else:src="img/Weather_icon/11.png" >
```

Comment: You should look into (ngIf) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf , (ngSwitch) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch and (ngClass) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive.

```
<img ng-src="{{ h > 10 ? 'a.png' : 'b.png'}}" />
```

Comment: seems good answer, tell me if i have more if statements.. i mean multiple else if statements..

Comment: If you have a more complex logic you should define a function in your controller that will handle it and in your template you could just say something like <img ng-src="{{getSrc()}}" />